# Java syntax int from char magic

Tags: java, char

I'm playing around on LeetCode to freshen up my algorithmic skills and for a specific task, I found a genius solution with a syntax that I have never seen before.

So the task is pretty simple (or let's say short, but it's qualified as medium difficulty): Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters

The solution someone submitted:

> ```java
> class Solution {
>     public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
>         if (s.length() == 0) return 0;
>         
>         int[] freq = new int[256];
>         
>         for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
>             freq[i] = 0;
>         
>         
>         int i=0,j=0;
>         int n = s.length();
>         int ans = 1;
>         
>         freq[s.charAt(0) - ' ']++;
>         
>         while(j < n-1){
>             if(freq[s.charAt(j+1) - ' '] == 0){
>                 freq[s.charAt(j+1) -' ']++;
>                 j++;                  
>             }else{            
>                 freq[s.charAt(i)-' ']--;
>                 i++;
>             }
>             ans = Math.max(ans,j-i+1);
>         }
>         return ans;
>        
>     } 
> }
> ```

My question is regarding the parts where we subtract `' '`
What is this syntax (is this Java specific) and for a bonus point how would you try to search for this to learn more about it?

Comment: It's an "implicit conversion". Read more about them e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) (a bit old, but still relevant). Yours is a case of "Widening Primitive Conversion".

Comment: Also relevant: [primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Thx guys! I would accept the first comment as an answer, but it's been deleted for some reason.

Comment: Be aware, the code as shown will blow up with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `s` contains any characters below U+0020 (space) or beyond U+011F (ğ).